# How to deal with "low quality" code?

Tags: discussion

I ask myself what to do, if someone posts realy "bad" code ...

- ignore it
- downvote (and tell them why)
- spend the time for improving this code (even if there is a already an accepted answer)
- ask a new question *"how to do THIS better"*

IMHO I use SE for a long time (just started answering some weeks ago), but this should not only be a place where you find answers ... it should - at least - try give you some hints about doing it better ...

Therefore I started "[ECG compliance: How to do?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/178640/ecg-compliance-how-to-do) " ... just to leave some references to write "as good as possible" code.

---

Reason for this question is "[change order in php](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/179470/change-order-in-php)" or "[how to show the latest reviews on the homepage?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/178428/how-to-show-the-latest-reviews-on-the-homepage)" ... and i can fully understand Marius with his comment ...

> Note: this code hurts my eyes.

---

*If it would be possible I would add a new "flag" where you can link (serveral) questions to improved - and **community review** - code ....*